# Kentico UniPager Pagination absolute url links

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

UniPager Pagination. Is it possible to put absolute links instead of relative ones in "PreviousGroupURL" and "NextGroupURL"?

My code:

```
<PreviousPageTemplate>
    <a href="<%# URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("PreviousURL", true))) %>" >Previous</a>
</PreviousPageTemplate>
<NextPageTemplate>
            <a href="<%# URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("NextURL", true)))%>">Next</a>
        </NextPageTemplate>
        <PreviousGroupTemplate>
            <a href="<%# URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("PreviousGroupURL", true))) %>">...</a>
        </PreviousGroupTemplate>
        <NextGroupTemplate>
            <a href="<%# URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(Convert.ToString(Eval("NextGroupURL", true)))%>">...</a>
        </NextGroupTemplate>
```

HTML source page:

```
            <a href="http://local/en/test">Previous</a>                         
            <a href="/en/test">1</a>           
            &nbsp;           
            <span>2</span>           
            &nbsp;          
            <a href="/en/test?strona=3">3</a>                          
            <a href="http://local/en/test?strona=3" >Next</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your transformation use something like:

`<%# GetAbsoluteUrl(Eval<string>("NextGroupURL")) %>`

From https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/11_0/api/html/Methods_T_CMS_Helpers_URLHelper.htm

Comment: Brenden Kehren, I tried that way. it works for "PreviousURL" and "NextURL", but not for "PreviousGroupURL" and "NextGroupURL"

Answer (score -2):

Please refer below URLs - -

https://docs.xperience.io/k11/references/kentico-controls/generic-controls/paging-controls/unipager

https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/repeater-and-unipager-in-a-custom-control-(widget)

https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-unipager-not-working